# Photo/Image Viewer for Monotouch

Tags: ios, image, xamarin.ios, photo, viewer

I've googled a bit but could not find a simple Image Viewer class to use in my MonoTouch app.

I don't need to show image thumbnails neither a complete photo album (with multiple photos).

I just need an image viewer to show an UIImageView, allowing the common fullscreen/zoom operations.

Obviously such viewer could be implemented using a `UIViewController` subclass with `UIGestureRecognizer`, `UIScrollView` and `UINavigationBar` trickery, but I don't want to reinvent the wheel. Does anyone know about an open source component available ?

It would also be useful to host such component in the new [Xamarin Component Store](http://components.xamarin.com)

Thanks

Comment: Have you used the "Suggest a Component" link on the component store ? I can't see it on https://xamarin.uservoice.com/forums/145075-xamarin-component-ideas

Comment: Very nice, I suggested the component there. Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Here it is.](https://bitbucket.org/MaximKorobov/imageviewer/)

**Features:**

- Show both big images (larger than the screen) and small ones;
- One tap to close view, two taps to zoom in/out. Pinch to zoom is also available;
- Scrolling through available content. It's impossible to scroll image outside visible area. Thanks to `UIScrollView`'s `ContentSize` property.

**Suggestions for future:**

- I reduced code by removing `UINavigationBar` usage.
- Also it's nice to add `UIView`'s basic animation (fade in/out) when user opens/closes full screen image view.

**Some relative info:**

- Solution was strongly inspired by [this article](http://www.raywenderlich.com/10518/how-to-use-uiscrollview-to-scroll-and-zoom-content).
- As a starting point for patching I recommend [Xamarin's article](http://docs.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/content_controls/scroll_view/implement_tap-to-zoom).

Any bug reports and suggestions are welcome!

Comment: Yes, it would be really nice to add a fade transition for the open/close operations. Also I noticed that there's a delay to detect the 'single tap' on the picture (probable because of the timer you're using). Maybe it would be better to use a double-tap UIGestureRecognizer.

Comment: Done: Fade in/fade out transitions added; Better handling single and double taps (iOS method usage instead of timer); Red background for image was removed. It was used for debug purpose.

Comment: Nice. There are a few enhancements that could still be done, such as zooming to the touch position (instead of just setting the zoom scale).

Comment: Done: Zoom to user specified point instead of center.

Comment: This works great except the image does not rotate with the device. Is anyone else having a problem with it rotating?

Comment: Make a pull request! :) I switched from monotouch to native tools.

Comment: This is absolutely awesome. Easy peasy

Comment: I'm very happy that code works 2+ years after it was done.